# How can I fetch data from the database that is associated with the user in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am really new to codeigniter but I decided to use it in my project. I have been able to build the dashboard but my challenge is that when i fetched the data from the database, it was giving me all the data in the database, not the one that is particular to the logged in user. For PDO, i can figure this out but I don't know how I would do this in codeigniter. Can any person help me with the correct code. I will past the PDO code here but how would I do this in codeigniter. I want to fetch the user where mobileNumber = mobileNumber. Thanks as i await some response.

````
$query=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE (mobileNumber=:mnumber || emailId=:emailid)");
      $query->execute(array(':username'=> $username));
       while($row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $jan=$row['jan'];
        $feb=$row['feb'];
        $march=$row['march'];
       }```
````

Comment: which version are you using? CI 4.x or CI 3.x

Comment: I am using CI 3.x

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should set database configuration in *application/config/database.php*
For example,

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => 'mysql:host=localhost; dbname=myproject; charset=utf8;', //db connection string
    'hostname' => 'HOST',
    'username' => 'DBUSER_UNAME',
    'password' => 'DBUSER_PW',
    'database' => 'DB',
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo'
    /* Other configurations
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => TRUE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE */
);
```

You can also define more configurations, $db['default'], $db['db_1'], $db['db_2'], ecc..
More info about configuration [here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/configuration.html).

CodeIgniter is a MVC framework, it divides code into Models (classes that extends CI_Model), Views (php files with html, access data given from a controller) and Controllers(classes that extend CI_Model, get data from model and send to view).
You access databases in Models.
In the constructor, call `$this->load->database();`
It will open the db connection following the default configuration.
You can select the configuration passing it as string parameter, e.g `$this->load->database('db_1');`
You can also give the configuration array seen above to that method, but i think that's better if you edit the database configuration file.

Ok, now we're ready!

To run your query, you can write (in a method of a Model class):

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE (mobileNumber=? || emailId=?)", array($mobileNumber, $emailId));
foreach ($query->result() as $row){
        $jan=$row['jan'];
        $feb=$row['feb'];
        $march=$row['march'];
}
```

The framework will replace the question marks with array fields values, in the order you've specified them.
Other way to do this:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('userdata');
$this->db->where('mobileNumber', $mobileNumber);
$this->db->or_where('emailId', $emailId);
$query = $this->db->query();
foreach ($query->result() as $row){
    ...
}
```

There are also others possibilities of doing this, see docs.

I advise you to read [codeigniter docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/overview/index.html) carefully, it's not so long and it's quite easy for me.
I hope this response will be exhaustive, let me know!

Comment: I have configured the database. I can get data from the database, the challenge is that instead of fetching the data associated with the user, it will fetch the whole database content and display for every user, which should not be

Comment: If you get all the table records, you could have an issue on where clauses. If you upload your db table schema I can help you Better, also you can rub DESCRIBE TABLE userdata and post here the result.

Comment: If this works properly, the error could be rełative to the data you've inserted, they could be inconsistent